# Error in R using 'read.csv' comamnd with colClasses argument

Tags: r, csv

I'm using the following command:

```
data <- read.csv("tua_data.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c('character', 'integer', 'character', 'character', 'character', 'Date', 'integer', 'integer', 'character', 'character'))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got 'Reidsighed'
```

**Visual inspection of the csv file shows that all integer columns do, indeed, contain integers. I am not sure what 'Reidsighed' means.
Thanks!**

Comment: Are you sure that the integer columns contain only integers?

Comment: Can you import the file without the colClasses argument?  Then inspect the column type that R assigns by default, something must be strange with the column of interest.

Comment: @blakeoft read the bold faced text...

Comment: @SeñorO There's a difference between something containing integers and it being completely filled with integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this error message the 'Reidsighed' text is an important clue. It is R indicating that where it expected to find an integer it found the string "Reidsighed." Closer visual inspection shows that the Excel csv file was corrupted during transfer, so, indeed, R was finding a bit of text in which some dude named Reid actually sighed. Thanks to all for trying to help!